# Assigning Devise current_user to comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I was following following this online video ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BI_VnnOLSKY)) tutorial for a simple blog.

Inside these blog posts are comments.

In this tutorial the Devise gem was used and a migration was performed to assign add user_id to posts.

I did a migration of add_user_id_to_comments similar to was done in the user_id migration for posts.

```
class AddUserIdToComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :comments, :user_id, :integer
    add_index :comments, :user_id
  end
end
```

My models contain the following:

**Comment model**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :post
      belongs_to :user
end
```

**User model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

I can assign a comment to a user doing the following.

```
user = User.first
comment = Comment.first
comment.user = user
```

This works in the console but the problem I'm running into is the comments_controller.
I've tried to mimic the steps done with the post controller.

This is from the **Post controller** (which works fine)

```
    class PostsController < ApplicationController    
    before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]       
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]    
    before_action :post_auth, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]    

        def index    
            @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')    
        end    

        def new    
            #@post = Post.new    
            @post = current_user.posts.build    
        end    

        def create    
            #@post = Post.new(post_params)    
            @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)   

            if @post.save    
                redirect_to @post    
            else    
                render 'new'    
            end    
        end    

        def show    
        end    

        def edit    
        end    

        def update    
            if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :body))    
                redirect_to @post    
            else   
                render 'edit'    
            end    
        end    

        def destroy    
            @post.destroy    
            redirect_to root_path    
        end    

        private    

        def post_params    
            params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)    
        end   

        def find_post   
            @post = Post.find(params[:id])    
        end   

        # Checks if current user authored pin      
        def post_auth    
            if current_user != @post.user    
            redirect_to(root_path)    
            end    
        end    
    end
```

The **Comments controller** I'm having difficulty with

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

        before_action :find_comment, only: [:create, :destroy]    
        before_action :comment_auth, only: [:destroy]    

        def create    
            #@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])    
            #@comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))    
            #redirect_to post_path(@post)

            #new format    
            @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])    
            #post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)    
            @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)    
            redirect_to post_path(@post)    
        end   

        def destroy    
            @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id]).destroy    
            redirect_to post_path(@post)   
        end    

        private    

        def comment_params    
            params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :body)    
        end   

        def find_comment    
            @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])    
        end   

        def comment_auth    
            if current_user != @post.user    
            redirect_to(root_path)   
            end    
        end     

    end
```

When I attempt to create a new comment; nothing happens...it redirects to the post page.
There are no errors returned however.

Your thoughts how to resolve this issue?
Any help will be appreciated.

> EDIT w/ SOLUTION

I was running into issues where the the '**name** and **body** values were not being passes to the database. After several attempts I finally was able to the **name** and **body** values passed with the following code:

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))
  @comment.user_id=current_user.id if current_user
  @comment.save

  if @comment.save
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
```

Thank you all for the assistance

Comment: Thank you for the replies.

Though the comments are being saved to the db, the post_id is not being passed along to the db. In the DB the post_id is NULL. I've tried doing the following:

`@comment = @post.current_user.comments.build(comment_params)`

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

```
@comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
```

You're calling `build` on your comments and then not saving them. You either need to `save` or use `create`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `build` method, an object is returned but it hasn't yet been saved to the database. You have two options:

1. Manually save the object:

   ```
   @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
   @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)  
   @comment.save!  
   redirect_to post_path(@post)
   ```

   or,
2. Use the `create` method, which automatically saves (note that I haven't tested this, feedback welcome if I'm telling lies!):

   ```
   @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
   @comment = current_user.comments.create(comment_params)
   redirect_to post_path(@post)
   ```

See the differences between the two in the [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) (emphasis mine):

> ```
> collection.build(attributes = {}, …)
> ```
>
> Returns one or more new objects of the collection type that have been instantiated with attributes and linked to this object through a foreign key, **but have not yet been saved**.
>
> ```
> collection.create(attributes = {})
> ```
>
> Returns a new object of the collection type that has been instantiated with attributes, linked to this object through a foreign key, and that **has already been saved** (if it passed the validation). Note: This only works if the base model already exists in the DB, not if it is a new (unsaved) record!

Answer (score 0):

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

   # Omitted some code code

    def create    
        #@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])    
        #@comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))    
        #redirect_to post_path(@post)

        #new format    
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])    
        #post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)    
        @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)    
        redirect_to post_path(@post)    
    end   

   # Omitted more code

end
```

In the create action, you did not save the `@comment`, rather you are only building it. You should call `@comment.save` or `current_user.comments.create(comment_params)`. To illustrate what I am saying:

Either this:

```
    def create    
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])    
        @comment = current_user.comments.create(comment_params)    
        redirect_to post_path(@post)    
    end
```

or this, will work.

```
    def create    
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])    
        @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
        @comment.save # returns true if save successful, false otherwise
        redirect_to post_path(@post)    
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a learner and even I have created same app and have found the way , just check if it helps. Solution is to add merge() to params

```
def create
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
  redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
private
 def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```